# How to show image at half or crop it's own size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried with many times but didnt happen ..

on img src i want to show only half image and when i will mouseover on that image it will show me the full image ... is it possible

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a property called [`clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip)

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fjZA/)

Comment: Why does the image need `position:absolute;`?

Comment: Just an FYI, doesn't work in IE 7, not sure if that is a concern for the OP

Comment: @Alex as per the w3c The clip property applies only to absolutely positioned elements. http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/clip

Comment: is it possible without position : absolute; ? because my design getting messup

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You could use a div with `overflow:hidden;` around the image. Change the size of the div instead the size of the image.

Example with jQuery:
http://jsfiddle.net/5GWCz/

Or CSS-Only:
http://jsfiddle.net/5GWCz/2/

Answer (score 0):

you can use CSS Image Sprites
for doing this 
look in this link

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp